# Jquery Data Table

Tags: jquery, datatables, alpacajs

```
$("#someDiv").alpaca({
    "jqdtdata": data.EntityList,
     "jqdtschema": [
               { "mData": "Eno" },
               { "mData": "Ename" },
               { "mData": "Date" },
               { "mData": "Age" },
               { "mData": "Email" },
               { "mData": "Gender" },
               { "mData": "State" },
               { "mData": "City" },
               { "mData": "Pin" },
               { "mData": "Phone" },
               { "mData": "Etype" }
    ],
    "jqdtui": "gvCust",
    "jqdtpaginate": false,
    "jqdtfilter": false,
    "jqdtInfo": false
});
```

I'm rendering a grid by using the alpaca library. The above code is working fine. But I don't understand what is jqdt and parameters like `jqdtui`, `jqdtpaginate`, `jqdtfilter` and `jqdtInfo`.
What are other parameter of jqdt?

In the above code we have used "someDiv" as default div to render. Is this default div to render in alpaca? instead of someDiv, if I take another div id, then it does not work properly.
Could somebody please explain this?

Comment: According to its documentation, Alpaca supports custom fields (http://alpacajs.org/docs/api/custom-fields.html). Is it possible that these are custom fields?

Comment: I think these are fields are of jquery datatable. I don't know what exactly it is. it is for rendering the record in grid of alpaca from database